# How do I reverse the output of a program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, binary, radix

I have to convert decimal numbers like 43.62  to binary. So i first wrote a basic program that converts 43 into binary. But I notice that my program prints out the binary number in reverse, so it prints 1 1 0 1 0 1 instead of 1 0 1 0 1 1. how can I fix this.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int remainder;

    cout << "Enter a integer: ";
    cin >> number;

    while(number != 0)
    {
        remainder = number % 2;
        cout << remainder << " ";
        number /= 2;
    }

    int pause;
    cin >> pause;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is homework, don't forget the homework tag.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of sending each digit to cout, send them to an array. Then read the array out in reverse order. Or push them onto a stack, and then pop them back off the stack. Or...

Comment: I know a little about arrays but my class has not learned this yet so I dont know if I should use a method that was not covered in class. Or should I?

Comment: The first rule of software development is that knowledge conquers all. Read ahead and learn about arrays! And Stacks! And linked lists! Keep going until your head explodes. And don't stop there.

Answer (score 3):

Something of a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but here's a solution based on a recursive approach:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void OutputDigit(int number)
{
    if (number>0)
    {
        OutputDigit(number /= 2);
        cout << number % 2 << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    OutputDigit(43);
    return 0;
}
```

You can get the same output as you had before by simply moving the `cout` one line up!

Answer (score 1):

Look at `vector` and think about how it could be useful to save the remainders instead of printing them right away.

Notice that you don't have to put things at the end of the vector.  `vector::insert` lets you specify a position... could that be helpful?

Alternatively, the algorithm you created starts at the least significant digit.  Is there a way to start from the most significant digit instead?  If I have the number 42 (`0101010`), the most significant digit represents the 32s, and the 0 ahead of it represents the 64s.  What happens if I subtract 32 from 42?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to store the results and then print them backwards. Using recursion is also another possibility to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Most significant bit first:

```
const unsigned int BITS_PER_INT = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int);
char bit_char = '0';
for (int i = BITS_PER_INT - 1;
     i > 0;
     --i)
{
    bit_char = (value & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';
    cout << bit_char << ' ';
}
cout << '\n';
cout.flush();
```

To print least significant bit first, change the direction of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can also use a bitset container to do this,

```
#include <bitset>

int i = 43;
std::bitset<sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT> bin(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use string functions

```
string s ;

while(number != 0)
{
    remainder = number % 2;
    string c = remainder ? "1": "0";
    s.insert(s.begin(),c.begin(),c.end());
    number /= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do such conversion by holding on to the remainder, the result will always be reverted. As suggested use `bitwise &`:

```
unsigned char bit = 0x80; // start from most significant bit
int  number = 43;
while(bit)
{
    if( bit & number ) // check if bit is on or off in your number
    {
       cout << "1";
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "0";
    }
    bit = bit >>1; // move to next bit
}
```

This example will start going through all your 8 bits of the number and check if the  bit is on or off and print that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Best option - Use C++ stringstream for formatting I/O**

```
// Add the following headers
    #include <sstream>
    #include <algorithm>

    // your function

    stringstream ss;

    // Use ss in your code instead of cout


    string myString = ss.str();
    std::reverse(myString.begin(),myString.end());
    cout << myString;
```